# Run Function on Textbox Blur in C#

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, what event do you attach an event to for when a textbox loses focus?  My function would be something like this:

```
private void txtModifier1_Blur(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code...
}
```

... and I would assign it like this:

```
this.txtModifier1.Blur += new System.EventHandler(this.txtModifier1_Blur);
```

... but there is no `Blur`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you specify - is this winforms? wpf? Asp.Net?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is Windows Forms, you're looking for the `Leave` event.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [Windows forms TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48deaakc) control. It has a [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus) event, inherited from `Control`. There is also the [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave) event. You should use the Leave event in most cases. See the notes on both the MSDN pages I've linked.

Something like this:

```
this.txtModifier1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.txtModifier1_Leave);
```

If you're using the [WPF TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx), then again, it has a [LostFocus event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus) inherited from `UIElement`

Answer (score 2):

[Lost Focus for asp.net textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863927/lost-focus-method-for-asp-net-textbox)

[Lost Focus for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103575/wpf-validation-not-firing-on-first-lostfocus-of-the-textbox)

[Lost Focus for WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx)